# How to get rid of Go vet warning % in Println

Tags: go

This code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("%%dude")
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/Shq5pMHg4bj

gives a `go vet` warning

```
./prog.go:8:2: Println call has possible formatting directive %d
```

How can I tell go vet that I really want to write two percent signs and not to warn me?

Comment: Replace the second (or both) % with \x25

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't really supress that, but even if you could with custom rules and flags, I wouldn't do it because someone else building your code will still run into this.

Instead you may use any of these alternatives which produce the same output without any warnings from `vet`:

```
fmt.Println("%%"+"dude")
fmt.Println("%\x25dude")
fmt.Printf("%%%%dude\n")
s := "%%dude"
fmt.Println(s)
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d6fp6pNSjP-).

Comment: Thanks. A comment such as `// go vet: I really mean %%` could solve this in all code bases.

Comment: @topskip There was a discussion about that (see [proposal: cmd/vet: add mechanism to silence false positives #17058](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17058)) which was declined.

Comment: I am trying to print "%sign"

All of there result in complaints from 'go vet'
fmt.Println("%sign")
fmt.Println("\x25sign")
fmt.Println("%" + "sign")

Is my only option to split it Into two print calls?
fmt.Print("%")
fmt.Println("sign")

Comment: @drhender If you want a single print call without variables, you may do `fmt.Printf("%%sign\n")` or `fmt.Printf("%ssign\n", "%")` or `fmt.Printf("%s\n", "%sign")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really (apart from not writing that code). Go vet doesn't have any mechanism for "I really meant this" comments to suppress warnings. There have been several discussions about it in the past five years, none of which have resulted in any action. You just have to accept what the help text says: go vet "uses heuristics that do not guarantee all reports are genuine problems".

Comment: Oh well, I guess I have to accept this answer... Thank you very much for it.